# How to find & replace a pattern with string in ruby?

Tags: shell, regex, ruby

My file is:

```
    [root@test etc]# cat nrpe.cfg

    command[check_users]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users -w 30 -c 35
    command[check_load]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_load -w 15,10,5 -c 30,25,20
    command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sda1
    command[check_hda]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20% -c 10% -p /dev/sdb
    command[check_procs]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_procs -w 200 -c 250
```

I Want to replace */dev/sdb* with */dev/xvda1* in ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.write('nrpe.cfg', File.read('nrpe.cfg').gsub('/dev/sdb', '/dev/xvda1'))
```